# average speed: how it's more than speeds which are used to calculate it

Tags: acceleration, speed

I'm not sure if that's what you call it... anyway, we need to calculate speed for some distance for accelerated object
$a=4m/s^2$ , $x_0=0m$ 
$t_1=0.5s$ , $x_1=1m$ so $v_1=2m/s$
$t_2=1s$ , $x_2=4m$ so $v_2=4m/s$
$$averageSpeed=\frac{x_2-x_1}{t_2-t_1}$$
$$\frac{4-1}{1-0.5}=\frac{3}{0.5}=6m/s$$
$$averageSpeed = v_1 + v_2$$
It makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

You should have x1 = 0.5m and x2 = 2m.

So the average speed between t1 and t2 is 1.5m / 0.5s = 3 m/s.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions in your problem are not compatible. The equation of motion is $x(t) = at^2/2 + v_0 t + x_0$, so if you look at the second line of the conditions, or $x_1 = 1$ m, $t_1 = 0.5$ s, it gives you $v_0=1$ m/s, while the third line gives $v_0=0$.